# How to reassign an individual element of a 2D parallel vector with a 1D vector?

Tags: c++, vector, populate

Hi I am working on an assignment for my introduction to C++ class and I am completely stumped on a certain part. Basically the assignment is to open a file that contains individual integers (the data represents a grid of elevation averages), populate a 2D vector with those values, find the min and max value of the vector, convert each element of the vector to a 1D parallel vector containing the RGB representation of that value (in Grey scale), and export the data as a PPM file. I have successfully reached the point where I am supposed to convert the values of the vector to the RGB parallel vectors.

My issue is that I am not entirely sure how to assign the new RGB vector to the original element of the vector. Here is the code I have currently:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main () {

  // initialize inputs
  int rows;
  int columns;
  string fname;

  // input options
  cout << "Enter number of rows" << endl;
  cin >> rows;
  cout << "Enter number of columns" << endl;
  cin >> columns;
  cout << "Enter file name to load" << endl;
  cin >> fname;
  ifstream inputFS(fname);

  // initialize variables
  int variableIndex;
  vector<vector<int>> dataVector (rows, vector<int> (columns));
  int minVal = 0;
  int maxVal = 0;

  // if file is open, populate vector with data from file
  if(inputFS.is_open()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < dataVector.size(); i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < dataVector.at(0).size(); j++) {
        inputFS >> variableIndex;
        dataVector.at(i).at(j) = variableIndex;
      }
    }
  }

  // find max and min value within data set
  for (int i = 0; i < dataVector.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < dataVector.at(0).size(); j++) {
      if (dataVector.at(i).at(j) < minVal) {
        minVal = dataVector.at(i).at(j);
      }
      if (dataVector.at(i).at(j) > minVal) {
        maxVal = dataVector.at(i).at(j);
      }
    }
  }

  // initialize variables and new color vector
  // -------PART I NEED HELP ON-----------
  int range = maxVal - minVal;
  int remainderCheck = 0;
  double color = 0;
  vector<int> colorVector = 3;

  for (int i = 0; i < dataVector.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < dataVector.at(0).size(); j++) {
      remainderCheck = dataVector.at(i).at(j) - minVal;
      if (remainderCheck / range == 0) {
        cout << "Color 0 error" << endl;
        // still need to find the RGB value for these cases
      }
      else {
        color = remainderCheck / range;
        fill(colorVector.begin(),colorVector.end()+3,color);
        dataVector.at(i).at(j) = colorVector; // <-- DOESN'T WORK
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My knowledge with C++ is very limited so any help would be greatly appreciated. Also if you have any advice for the other comment dealing with the / operator issues in the same chunk of code, that too would also me incredibly appreciated.

Here are the actual instructions for this specific part:

Step 3 - Compute the color for each part of the map and store
The input data file contains the elevation value for each cell in the map. Now you need to compute the color (in a gray scale between white and black) to use to represent these evaluation values. The shade of gray should be scaled to the elevation of the map.

Traditionally, images are represented and displayed in electronic systems (such as TVs and computers) through the RGB color model, an additive color model in which red, green, and blue light are added together in various ways to reproduce a broad array of colors. In this model, colors are represented through three integers (R, G, and B) values between 0 and 255. For example, (0, 0, 255) represents blue and (255, 255, 0) represents yellow. In RGB color, if each of the three RGB values are the same, we get a shade of gray. Thus, there are 256 possible shades of gray from black (0,0,0) to middle gray (128,128,128), to white (255,255,255).

To make the shade of gray, you should use the min and max values in the 2D vector to scale each integer (elevation data) to a value between 0 and 255 inclusive. This can be done with the following equation:

color =(elevation - min elevation)(max elevation - min elevation) * 255

Check your math to ensure that you are scaling correctly. Check your code to make sure that your arithmetic operations are working as you want. Recall that if a and b are variables declared as integers, the expression a/b will be 0 if a==128 and b==256.

As you compute the shade of grey, store that value in three parallel vectors for R, G and B. Putting the same value for R, G and B will result in grey. The structure of the vector should mirror the vector with the elevation data.

Comment: `vector<int> colorVector = 3;` will initialize a vector of size 1 with value 3. In the line `dataVector.at(i).at(j) = colorVector; // <-- DOESN'T WORK`, you try to assign a vector to a cell in the elevation map, where each cell is a number. You cannot assign a vector to an integer. Read your assignment: You are asked to fill three separate vectors for "R", "G", and "B". Also note that you don't use the formula from the assignment at all, and that you fell into the trap of integer division mentioned in the text (`remainderCheck / range`).

Comment: `fill(colorVector.begin(),colorVector.end()+3,color);` -- No, don't add anything to `end()`. This will crash your program. Make sure that the vector has size 3 before calling `fill()`.

Comment: And check your calculation of `maxVal`: There is a bug.

Comment: Also notice that `minVal` will be computed incorrectly if the smallest elevation is greater than 0. All checks of the actual data to the initial minimum will return false.

Answer (score 0):

Your professor is asking you to make three additional `vector<vector<int>>`s: 1 for each of R, G, and B. (I do not know *why* you need three separate vectors: they will have identical values, since for grayscale R==G==B for every element. Still, follow instructions.)

```
typedef std::vector <int>      row_type;
typedef std::vector <row_type> image_type;

image_type dataVector( rows, row_type( columns ) );

image_type R         ( rows, row_type( columns ) );
image_type G         ( rows, row_type( columns ) );
image_type B         ( rows, row_type( columns ) );
```

Also, be careful whenever you do something like `fill(foo.begin(),foo.end()...)`. Attempting to fill *beyond* the end of the container (`foo.end()+3`) is **undefined behavior**.

Load your dataset into `dataVector` as before, find your min and max, then for each element find the grayscale value (in [0,255]). Assign that value to each corresponding element of `R`, `G`, and `B`.

Once you have those three square vectors, you can use them to create your PPM file.